# How to position elements as a curve with jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is a slightly unusual request as I know there are plugins out there to position elements along a bezier curve, however for a variety of reasons that I won't go into, these methods are not applicable for this application.

I need to iterate through a set of elements using the jQuery each function and emulate a curve that curves to the left, from bottom to top.

Like so:-

```
  O
 O
O
O
O
 O
  O
```

I need store the number of elements in a variable using .size()

And from this number perform a calculation to work out the css left property, dependant upon the index of the element.

Math is unfotunately not my strong point and I am stuck on the formula to use, and how I would go about iterating through the elements using jQuery .each() and apply the css changes to each element.

The number of elements will be changing dynamically which is why the both the number of the elements and the index of each element will need to be included in the formula.

Can anyone give me at least a starting point as to how I would go aboout coding this in jQuery? (or using the position addon in jqueryUI)

Comment: See the update to my answer. (the fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a bit complicated. but you need to make sure all the elements have a position:

`relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` in order to position them like that.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PPRKF/

Comment: Thanks i should have said, they already are, it is only the left property of each element in the group that i need to modify based on its index and the total number of elements.

Comment: @gordyr see example I just added.

Comment: Fantastic! What a simple solution... Thank you so much. Although it is not quite a curve, it will be fine for my application, and i'm certain I can modify your code from here to get the result I need.  As soon as I am able I will accept the answer. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @gordyr no problem ^_^ glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a jQuery plugin to do just this [jCurvy](http://jcurvy.com/index.html)

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KTMsA/)

---

It even comes with a nice design interface to generate the point codes for you to curve your elements the way you want here http://jcurvy.com/design.html?design=1

Simply drag and drop the `test1`, `test9`, and the red `1`/`2` points to shape the curve how you want and the code is generate above to use with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Jeff.... The curve is indeed much better and would be exactly what I want however, this plugin also changes the height position of the elements depending on how many there are, resulting in differences.  Perhaps I can poke around in the code and modify it.

Comment: Simple... I've modified the plugin and it now does exactly what I want.  Beautiful.  I feel I should leave Neal with the 'answer' though as it directly answered my question, even though your solution is what I have ultimately gone with.  I hope thats okay.  Many thanks for your help!